# Concept Behind Static classes in Java

Tags: java, static, static-classes

Consider the following code

```
class A {
    static class B{
        int a = 0;
    }
    public static void main(String argc[]) {
        B var1 = new B();
        B var2 = new B();
        var1.a = 5;
        var2.a = 6;
        System.out.println(var1.a+" and "+var2.a);
    }
}
```

It outputs 5 and 6.
Static members are loaded only once.But the output contradicts with that statement.So surely the concept  of static classes is different from static data members.So what does static mean in case of static classes

Comment: Don't confuse static classes with instances of the class. There is only one class B, but you can have an unlimited number of B instances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A copy paste from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

**Static Nested Classes**

As with class methods and variables, a static nested class is associated with its outer class. And like static class methods, a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class — it can use them only through an object reference.

**Note:** A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, **a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.**
Static nested classes are accessed using the enclosing class name:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass
```

For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
     new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

An example:

There is no need for LinkedList.Entry or Map.Entry to be top-level class as it is only used by LinkedList aka Map. And since they do not need access to the outer class members, it makes sense for it to be static - it's a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Could you add an example where a static nested class can be useful?

Comment: @KirillKulakov [`Map.Entry<K,v>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a good example.

Comment: Personally i use them when implementing the builder pattern, check the book effective java by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood the concept. `B` is a static class with an `int a` attribute. In your code, you're creating two instances of the `B` class and each instance has its own `a` attribute with its value 5 and 6 respectively. Don't confuse the static class with the static attribute/method of a class.

The behavior you're trying to get can be done if you add the `static` modifier to the `a` attribute on the `B` class. Otherwise, your code it's like this:

```
class B{
    int a = 0;
}

class A {
    public static void main(String argc[]) {
        B var1 = new B();
        B var2 = new B();
        var1.a = 5;
        var2.a = 6;
        System.out.println(var1.a+" and "+var2.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JanDvorak AFAIK this answer the question. `B` is a static class but its behavior is not like a `static` attribute.

Comment: The question was, "what is a static class", not "how do I achieve the expected output"

Comment: How can an answer to "So what does static mean in case of static classes" start with "You're wrong?"

Comment: @JinuJD Is Frank's answer good for you or should I try to write one?

Comment: @Yar because OP is confusing the terms. I haven't add the `static class` definition but went to explain why the codes doesn't behave as OP though. Is that wrong?

Comment: @JanDvorak maybe this is not a direct answer but explains the misconception on OP about static classes vs static attributes.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak:I got the concept from that answer.." a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class "...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OP doesn't want to be corrected - he wants to be taught. There's no myth to bust, only blanks to fill.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Note that you've collected +3/-3 - this means I'm not alone in my opinion.

Comment: @JanDvorak and I'm not alone in my answer :). The important thing here is to show OP the right way, and Frank did it, still my answer can help OP about the code sample behavior.

Comment: The OP is wrong in considering the static class to be a static member that is only loaded once.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza if it's "not a direct answer" then it should be a comment on the question. And instead of "you're wrong" try something like, "it seems you've confused the terms." See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette. "Nice" es subjetivo en inglés, pero es lo mismo que entendés por "tratar a los demás con el máximo de respeto incluso si no entienden un pimiento" en tu idioma ;)

Comment: @Yar okay, fixed the way the answer started. And not, this should be an answer, not a comment. Por cierto, no creo haber faltado el respeto a nadie con mi respuesta ni mis comentarios, pero en caso que lo hubiese hecho favor de indicármelo para corregirlo de inmediato :).

Comment: All good, thanks for fixing that and good luck here on SO, salu2!

Answer (score 3):

Static, in case of classes, means that they are not related to an instance of their outer class:

```
class A{
  class B{
    ...
  }
}
...
new A.B(); //error
```

is invalid. Because B is not static, it holds an implicit reference to an instance of A. This means you cannot create an instance of B without an instance of A.

```
class A{
  static class B{
    ...
  }
}
...
new A.B();
```

is perfectly valid. Since B is static, it doesn't hold a reference to A, and can be created without an instance of A existing.

Static class is a class that doesn't hold an implicit reference to its enclosing class. **Static class behaves just like an ordinary class** except its namespace being within another class.

**Non-static inner class holds an implicit reference to its enclosing class**. The enclosing class' variables are directly accessible to an instance of the inner class. A single instance of the outer class can have multiple instances of its inner class(es).

Comment: It became more clear!...Thanks for the answer..So it's just a way of packaging classes